# Cosine interpolation

Tags: interpolation, trigonometry

Suppose I have a list of values of a function $f(x)$ at positive integer points, say
$$f(1) = -0.5, f(2) = -0.5, f(3) = 1, f(4) = -0.5, f(5) = -0.5, f(4) = 1,...$$
Can I interpolate a cosine function, i.e. a function $\cos(2\pi xc)$ for some constant $c$ given such a set of points, and then calculate the period? The example I gave listed values of $\cos(2\pi x/3)$.

I know mathematica has an Interpolate command, but this seems to just produce a graph interpolating the points you input.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the various `*Fit` functions, `FindFit`, `NonlinearModelFit`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure how to use FindFit though. The help page http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html example
     FindFit[%, axLog[b + cx], {a,b,c}, x]
doesn't explain how to input the points to be interpolated.

Comment: Clear[c];data={{1,-.5},{2,-.5},{3,1},{4,-.5},{5,-.5}};
c=c/.FindFit[data,Cos[2 Pi c x],{c},x];
Print[Table[{x,Cos[2 Pi x  c]},{x,1,5}]];
Show[ListPlot[data],Plot[Cos[2 Pi x  c],{x,1,5}]] That probably shows it isn't what you are hoping for, even though it goes through all your data points.

Comment: @Bill -- all you need do is change your `{c}` to `{{c, 0.2}}` and your answer works perfectly.

Comment: Note that there is not a unique solution.

Comment: What happen if we have values of the derivatives? That is to say a list of point in the form {x,f[x],f'[x],f''[x]} Thanks

Comment: @jes please don't use answers as follow up questions. Ask a separate one instead. But make sure it follows [asking standards](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

One way is with NoninearModelFit:

```
data = {{1, -.5}, {2, -.5}, {3, 1}, {4, -.5}, {5, -.5}}; 
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data[[All, 2]], Cos[2 Pi c x], {{c, 0.2}}, x];
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 1, 5}, Epilog :> Point[data], PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick}]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that if the abscissae are not consecutive integers starting with `1`, one should simply use `data` instead of `data[[All, 2]]`.  (One could simply use `data` in all cases, I suppose.)